# Windows store app 8.1 - Background Task not triggered

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, background-task

I am very new to Windows Store App and I am trying to use a background task.

I register it on a button click event this way:
             var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

```
         builder.Name = "bikePositionUpdate";
         builder.TaskEntryPoint = "BackgroundTaskGps.BikeGPSPositionUpdateBackgroundTask";
         builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false)); // 

         BackgroundTaskRegistration taskRegistration = builder.Register();
```

So it is supposed to be launched within 15'.

Here is my task:

```
namespace BackgroundTaskGps
{
    public sealed class BikeGPSPositionUpdateBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
             Debug.WriteLine("run run run");
        }
    }
}
```

and here my manifest

```
...
      <Extensions>
        <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="BackgroundTaskGps.BikeGPSPositionUpdateBackgroundTask">
          <BackgroundTasks>
            <Task Type="timer" />
          </BackgroundTasks>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>
...
```

But run method is never hit.

Please what could be my problem?

PS: I am testing my app on my local machine (the same development PC).

**Please consider that I am not talking about Windows Phone App but Windows App**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows Phone You must need to call this

```
await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
```

So the complete code is

```
await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
 builder.Name = "bikePositionUpdate";
         builder.TaskEntryPoint = "BackgroundTaskGps.BikeGPSPositionUpdateBackgroundTask";
         builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false)); //For Windows Phone 8.1 minimum is 15 minutes

         BackgroundTaskRegistration taskRegistration = builder.Register();
```

Comment: WP 8.1 minimum time is 30 minutes.

Comment: No it is 15 minutes. I am running my app at 15 minutes.

Comment: You never know when exactly the Background task triggers. It can be anywhere between 0 and 30 minutes. I have seen background task ending and starting at the same minute. There is no way to find out when it starts or when it stops, atleast in Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: Link here 'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh977056.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396' it says 30 minutes for WP. But yeah, I've seen events trigger five minutes after being setup.

Comment: Please consider that I am not talking about Windows Phone App but Windows App

Answer (score 0):

You are using TimeTrigger Task in response to a Trigger(fire). The minimum time between TimeTrigger Task must be 30 minutes. So you can perform a background task after every 30 minutes. It's similar to the Periodic Trigger in windows 8. So your Updated code line would be:

```
builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(30, false));
```

Comment: Minimum time is 15 minutes for Store Apps, but it's 30 minutes for the Phone.

Comment: Please consider that I am not talking about Windows Phone App but Windows App